# Using python class.instance after creation

Tags: python, class, csv, persistence, instance

I need to move images from several directories into one and capture metadata on the files before and after the move.

In each directory:

- Read the index of jpg images from indexfile.csv, including metadata on each image
- Upload the corresponding image file to google drive, with metadata
- Add entry to uberindex.csv which includes the metadata from indexfile.csv and the file url from google drive after upload

My plan was to create an instance of the class ybpic() -  def below – for each row of indexfile.csv and use that instance to identify the actual file to be moved ( it’s reference in the indexfile ), hold the metadata from the indexfile.csv,  then update that ybpic.instance with the results of the google drive upload ( the other metadata ) before finally writing out all of the instances to the uberindex.csv.

I know I’m going to kick myself when the answer comes ( real noob ).

I can csv.reader the indexfile.csv into a ybpic.instance but I’m not able refer to each instance individually to use or update the instance later.
I can just append the rows from indexfile.csv to indexlist[], and I’m able to return the updated list back to the caller but I don’t know a good way to then update that list row, for the corresponding image file, later with the new metadata.

Here's the ybpic def

```
class ybpic(): 

    def __init__(self,FileID, PHOTO, Source, Vintage, Students,Folder,Log):
        self.GOBJ=" "
        self.PicID=" "
        self.FileID=FileID
        self.PHOTO=PHOTO
        self.Source=Source
        self.Students=Students
        self.Vintage=Vintage
        self.MultipleStudents=" "
        self.CurrentTeacher=" "
        self.Folder=Folder ## This may be either the local folder or the drive folder attr
        self.Room=" "
        self.Log=Log ## The source csvfile from which the FileID came
```

Here is the function populating the instance and list.  The indexfile.csv is passed as photolog and cwd is just the working directory:

```
def ReadIndex(photolog, cwd, indexlist) :
    """ Read the CSV log file into an instance of YBPic. """

    with open(photolog,'r') as indexin :
        readout = csv.reader(indexin)

    for row in readout:
        indexrow=ybpic(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],cwd,photolog) 

        indexlist.append(row)       ### THIS WORKS TO APPEND TO THE LIST
                                    ### THAT WAS PASSED TO ReadIndex

return(indexlist)
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not directly related, but look at `glob`, specifically `glob.glob` (for getting a file listing using wildcards) and `shutil` for copying the files. Both are part of the built-in libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a list, you could use a dictionary of objects with PhotoID as the key (assuming it's stored in row[0]).

```
def ReadIndex(photolog, cwd, indexlist) :
    """ Read the CSV log file into an instance of YBPic. """

    ybpic_dict = {}       

    with open(photolog,'r') as indexin :
        readout = csv.reader(indexin)

    for row in readout:
        ybpic_dict[row[0]] = ybpic(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],cwd,photolog) 

    return ybpic_dict
```

Then when you need to update the attributes later

```
ybpic_dict[PhotoID].update(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since I found the answer myself, no kicks are in order....

Store the ybpic.instance object in a list.

The answer was, in the for loop which creates the instance of ybpic from the row of the indexfile, rather than putting the associated *values* for the instance in a list to be passed back to the caller, append the *actual object* of the instance into the list which is then passed back to the caller.  Once I'm back in the calling function, I then have access to the objects(instances).

I'm not sure this is the *best* answer, but it's the one that gets me moving to the next.

New code:

def ReadIndex(photolog, cwd, indexlist) :
        """ Read the CSV log file into an instance of YBPic. """

```
    with open(photolog,'r') as indexin :
        readout = csv.reader(indexin)

    for row in readout:
        indexrow=ybpic(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],cwd,photolog) 

        indexlist.append(indexrow)       ## Store the ybpic.indexrow     instance

return(indexlist)
```

.